# What is the difference between Html.Partial and Html.Action methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller, action which returns PartialViewResult and view with it. For testing I output current DateTime (in action), and in view I check if it is null or not, so I know what I got.

When I try to "embed" that view in another one with `Html.Action` I get current datetime, so my action is called.

But when I use `Html.Partial` the view is rendered with null, my action method is not called. Besides, two breakpoints and debugger also confirms, in latter case the my action method is not called.

Action method:

```
public PartialViewResult Test()
{
  return PartialView(DateTime.Now);
}
```

(partial) View:

```
@model DateTime?

<p>@(Model ?? DateTime.MinValue)</p>
```

and call from main view is either `@Html.Action("Test")` or `@Html.Partial("Test")`.

Comment: Can you show us the "main view"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Html.Action() will call your action method, but Html.Partial() will not. Html.Partial() just renders your partial view, and is useful if you have some static content, or if you've already loaded the view data.

```
Html.Partial("PartialName", Model.PartialData);
```

Will render the PartialName view with your model data passed to it. It's a great way to break up views into clean sections, without having to incur any additional requests to the server.

```
Html.Action("Test")
```

will call your Test action, and render the result.

This is why you're seeing the NULL DateTime. Html.Action() is actually calling the action, computing the DateTime, and rendering the view, whereas Html.Partial() is only rendering the view.

Comment: Can't he call `@Html.Partial("Test", new { DateTime.Now }`?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that too. You can even leave off the new {}, since DateTime is also valid as a Model. I think the question was more broadly about the difference between Html.Action and Html.Partial though, and the OP only mentioned the DateTime.Now as being for testing.

Comment: Do we really need to send `Model.Partialdata`? Main model of the page is automatically gets sent to partial views right? However if for efficiency purpose we just want to sent the particular "submodel" which is `PartialData` in above case then we need to use something like `Model.partialData`. can you kindly tell my understanding is correct or not?

Comment: I'm not sure if the main model is automatically sent to partial views and I don't have a setup to check. But the rest of your understanding is correct. You can either pass Model, or Model.PartialData to the partial. Whatever properties you want.